# when i include $this->load->library('session'); property session will destroy automatically

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

whenever i add `$this->load->library('session');`   property in code igniter function the session will destroy automatically ..
please help me about this..

controller function:

```
public function logged()
{    
   $this->load->library('session');
   $this->load->view('includes/header');
   $this->load->view('includes/nav');
   $this->load->view('index'); 
   $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

view page:

```
<h4><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('item'); ?></h4>
```

> Error:    A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$session
>
> Filename: views/index.php
>
> Line Number: 6
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ravi2\application\views\index.php Line: 6
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ravi2\application\controllers\welcome.php Line:
>   19 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ravi2\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Comment: `$this->load->library('session');` add this in constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add session library in autoload.php than load manually in your controller constructor as:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

*[Most Important from the Manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html): Because the Loader Class is instantiated by CodeIgniter’s base controller, make sure to call parent::__construct() before trying to load a library from inside a controller constructor.*

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```

And in view you can use like:

```
if($this->session->flashdata('item')){
   // to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:
1) Maybe just [auto-load](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) the session library in the autoload config file.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session');
```

OR, maybe you are by default and the secondary load in the controller function is killing the initial load.

2) If you can't autoload the session library, then maybe load it in the construct of the controller that the logged function is in.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');    
}
```

Comment: NO CHANGE:        Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function set_flashdata() on null

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ravi2\application\controllers\login.php

Line Number: 43

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ravi2\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Where are you actually setting this flash session variable:  $this->session->flashdata('item')?

Comment: @RaviReddy: add the condition as `if($this->session->flashdata('item')){
   // to do
}` in view file

Comment: in index.php view

Comment: will push into github if you help me out..?

Comment: A thought...CodeIgniter's "flashdata" will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.  So, depending upon what is going on in your login controller, you might want to set an actual session variable rather than a flashdata session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the flash data before viewing it, imo you're trying to echo the flashdata while its not set, this is how to use your sessions, first either load the session using the construct function on your controller using the :

```
 $this->load->library('session');
```

or auto-load the session helper in your libraries autoload, then set the flash data like so :

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata("flashdataname", "data");
```

Then always check if the flashdata is set before trying to echo it, ex :

```
if (!empty($this->session->flashdata("flashdataname"))) 
echo ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the session library in your constructor {magic method}

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Controller extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}
public function logged() {  
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('includes/nav');
    $this->load->view('index'); 
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
  }
}
```